# Need way to schedule one-time event (via openshift atq/batch job)

Tags: python, cron, openshift

I've been using openshift for about a month now to develop a python/django website. My question: Can I schedule an event to occur just one time which will execute a python program to run? I would use the 'at' command from a shell, but I get the message 'Permission denied' when tried. There is support for cron but I only want the event to trigger once, so I guess I could user cron and cancel the event after the first time, but that gets messy. Any suggestions? Thanks.

Comment: When do you want the event to he scheduled? If it's after your push to OS use an post action hook.

Comment: Thanks, but I'm not familiar with these 'post action hooks'. Can you point me to some documentation? Also, how do I push it to the OS when the 'at' command is not allowed (on openshift server). Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can do it from python with this

http://apscheduler.readthedocs.org/en/latest/

Comment: Thanks, but after reading the documentation, it seems like less overhead to just create a thread which will sleep the desired no. of seconds, run my python program and destroy itself upon exiting. (I don't need a database retention feature). I just wondered if 'at' could be activated on openshift. But thanks.